# How to make Recaptcha a required field in MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have recaptcha on my signup form.
The user must type something in the recaptcha box before it gets posted to the server.
I have server side validation and client side validation for other fields.

Generated html from rcaptcha:

```
<input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" autocomplete="off" class="valid">
```

View:

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "red", publicKey: GetPublicKey())
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.recaptcha_response_field)
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "'captcha required' ")]
public string recaptcha_response_field { get; set; }
```

On load I see the 'captcha required' message. But if I type something it still appears.
The form gets submitted with empty recaptcha box.

How can I make recaptcha required field at client side?

Thanks for helping

**EDIT:**
I added this to intercept the submit btn click event, but it doesn't stop from posting the form.

```
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="sprt bg_red bt_red h25" onsubmit="ValidateAndSubmit();">Signup</button>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function ValidateAndSubmit() {
            var v=$('#recaptcha_response_field').val();
            if (v == '' || v == undefined) {
                alert('captcha is required');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work as you type it, return the value, not just call it. Type

```
onsubmit="return ValidateAndSubmit();"
```

or

```
onclick="return ValidateAndSubmit();"
```

Also you can try to add the same validation on the form tag.

Comment: I agree that this should be done on the server - if you use logic in Javascript that determines that the recaptcha is required, a bot/script could easily be written that overlooks that check.

Comment: @serotonic if you see its only check that have something on it, not if its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is pretty old, thought it it might help to share my solution, that supports MVC unobtrusive javascript.

```
if ($("#recaptcha_response_field").length > 0) {
  $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("data-val", "true")
    .attr("data-val-required", "The captcha field is required.");
  $("<span />")
    .attr("data-valmsg-replace", "true")
    .attr("data-valmsg-for", "recaptcha_response_field")
    .addClass("field-validation-valid")
    .appendTo($("#recaptcha_response_field").parents(".editor-field"));
}
```